# TFS Release Deploy Comment

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a release definition in TFS and I've set it up for manual deploys to dev.  When I create the release I add a comment of 805.  You can see this in the following image under details.

[image]

Now when I go to deploy to dev I add a different comment 810...

[image]

Now the deployment runs and looking in the logs, I can see the comment I entered when I created the release (805) but nowhere to be found is the comment when I entered the comment during deployment (810)...

[image]

I can see the 810 when clicking history...

[image]

My question... Can I access the deployment comment from release variables or any other way from a step that runs during deployment?  I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you want to do with the message?

Comment: Actually I'd like the ability to set variables at deployment time to link the deployment to a change tracking system.  Since that doesn't exist during release (it does during build), I was going to use that deployment comment to link back to the change number, but it doesn't seem that variable is available to scripting.

Answer (score 0):

The 805 here is the release description, while 810 here is a deployment comment. There is no such release variable for a deployment comment.